# jQuery Mobile login handler

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile, authentication

I started to develop a web application as a major project for my degree. Purpose of app is not important. My problem is handling the login. I have no problem with setting up login with jQuery mobile, that is actualy working pretty well. Problem is I'm handling login with php script through ajax and creating session in that process. So for checking if user is logged in or not I'd normaly use a php script, but in this case I can't. I need to keep using only client side for authentication. What would be the solution for this? Can I handle authentication with some native jQuery functions or do I need to write some JS scripts? If anyone have any solution please I don't need actual code, just best solution. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure you can make authentication without a server side. But what's the problem of using php with mobile devices?

Comment: Actually, I'm sure you can't

Comment: In future I would like to be able to use this web app as an install-able web app for Firefox OS, and as far as I know, I need all the files there with client side scripting. Or do I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this as long as login authentication is restricted to the device. What I mean is that user-id / password combination can be stored locally on the device. You may choose local file system storage for this. Here are the steps:

1) Make user register with uid/password
2) Check uid is existing in your local storage. If not register by writing it to local storage.
3) Later when user returns, validate login credentials against the local store.

Comment: So there is nothing to stop someone looking in the local storage and seeing the user ID and password in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're developing a native app with a mobile web framework. In this case you have two choices:

- POST the login details out to a server somewhere, authenticate and return the session, allowing the user access. This will obviously require internet access, but will be more secure.
- Store the credentials in [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) using JavaScript when the user signs up. Encrypt this value and compare against it when the user logs in.